# Report vewier cannot add parameters

Tags: vb.net, parameters, reportviewer

I have managed to set a dataset to my tablix on my report viewer that will hold all items belonging to a bill. The issue I present you with is I cannot seem to add any parameters to my textboxes in my .rdlc report. Is this because I have added a connection to my database? Before I added my connection I could easily add parameters, but not anymore. Take a look at my report:

[image]

All the red rectangles is where I would usually have my parameters. Is there a way to programmatically do this?

```
Dim rpJobNum = New ReportParameter("tbJobNo", JobNum)
rv.rvRdlc.LocalReport.SetParameters(rpJobNum)
```

**rv** is my report viewer form

**rvRdlc** is my report viewer control

**tbJobNo** is my textbox' job number name

**JobNum** is a variable which holds the respective value (ex: 10000)

If I execute that,I will receive an error:

[image]

Any idea why I cannot seem to add any parameter controls? Perhaps there's another way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out why I couldn't add parameters. Pretty noob stuff on my part.

Go to **View** > **Report Data**

[image: Ctrl + Alt + D]

Or... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

My apologies, but, I'll answer this if it can help someone!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim parmlist As New List(Of ReportParameter)()
parmlist.Add(New ReportParameter("tbJobNo ", JobNum))
print.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parmlist)
```

you need to create a list, as i did here

Comment: No, that does not add the parameter to the report. What you are doing here is assigning a value to an existing parameter "tbJobNo" ... Which in my case was not added. I had to add it using the Report Data tool, where you create your parameters.